# Different kappa results from kappa2() and CohenKappa()

Tags: r, cohens-kappa

I am trying to compute a weighted kappa with confidence intervals in R.

I am having trouble understanding why the two functions, DescTools::CohenKappa and irr::kappa2, give different outputs. I need to use the former (DescTools::CohenKappa) as I need the confidence intervals, but would like to know why these produce different results?

DescTools::CohenKappa

```
   kappa      lwr.ci      upr.ci 
-0.24584718 -0.45930367 -0.03239068
```

irr::kappa2

```
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: 0,0.25,1)

 Subjects = 20 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0.378 

        z = 1.71 
  p-value = 0.0878
```

I don't think I've made any error in the coding. Just in case, here is an example:

```
library(irr)
library(DescTools)

## Data

test = structure(list(fi.cat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("non-frail","prefrail", "frail"), class = "factor"), 
                      fp.cat = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                           1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                                           2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("non-frail", "prefrail", "frail"), class = "factor")), 
                 row.names = c(NA,20L), class = "data.frame")

## DescTools::CohenKappa

m = table(test$fi.cat, test$fp.cat) # create confusion matrix (i.e. cross tabulation)

wm = matrix(c(
  0, 0.25, 1,
  0.25, 0, 0.25,
  1, 0.25, 0), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE # my weights
)

kappa1 = DescTools::CohenKappa(m, weights=wm, conf.level=0.95) 

## irr::kapp2

kappa2 = irr::kappa2(test[, c("fi.cat", "fp.cat")], c(0, 0.25, 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, `DescTools::CohenKappa` has

```
 W <- if (is.matrix(weights))
    weights
```

and `irr::kappa2` has

```
    if (is.numeric(weight))
        w <- 1-(weight-min(weight))/(max(weight)-min(weight))
```

So it looks as though `irr::kappa2` transforms the weights it is given and `DescTools::CohenKappa` doesn't

Comment: Thank you Thomas, it wasn't clear from the documentation that the weights were transformed. That explains the inconsistency but now I am stuck trying to apply the weights that I want to use. Possibly another post coming up soon.....